# How to add color BarLegend here?

Tags: plotting, legending

How can I add a `BarLegend` to the following plot?

```
b[x_] := x;
p1 = 
  Show[
    Graphics[
      Table[{Hue[i/20], Circle[{0, 0}, b[i]]}, {i, 1, 6, 0.1}], 
      ImageSize -> 350
    ], Frame -> True
  ]
```

Comment: Have you already seen `Legended[]`?

Comment: yes. Not working.

Comment: Well, the hope was that you'd see that `Legended[]` needs a second argument that is something like `BarLegend[{Hue[#/20] &, {1, 6}}]`, depending on what you are trying to do (which you have not mentioned so far in your question, but should have been there).

Comment: Here if you run this code, you will see colored concentric circles dur to Hue. I want to show in the BarLegend that color variation with i.

Comment: You should edit your question to include that information instead of putting it here in the comments.

Comment: okay but  BarLegend[{Hue[#/20] &, {1, 6}}]  is also not working here.

Comment: @AkhilUniyal See my answer, but I am not sure if I understand your question, particularly since the `BarLegend` expression you mentioned does seem to work for me. If what you see in my answer is not what you want, then perhaps you can explain further.

Comment: @MarcoB Yes, that is exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: @AkhilUniyal You can accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: @MarcoB HI, is this also possible to give colors to the circles by some other parameter say : area. So, the colors and color bar will show the area of the circles not the radius. Is this possible to do? It is not working in this way.

Comment: @AkhilUniyal Yeah, it can be done, but it is different enough from this question that it probably warrants asking a new question about it.

Comment: @MarcoB posted new question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ClearAll[b]
b[x_] := x

Legended[
 Graphics[
   Table[{Hue[i/20], Circle[{0, 0}, b[i]]}, {i, 1, 6, 0.1}],
   ImageSize -> 350, Frame -> True
 ],
 BarLegend[{Hue[#/20] &, {1, 6}}]
]
```

[image: concentric circles and legend]